# Ping com Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Alguém possui alguma classe que faça o teste ping em Objective-C? Tentei diversas e não consegui com nenhuma.

Preciso apenas pegar o IP e fazer o teste, se "pingar" executar a ação, do contra, apenas emitir uma mensagem de host inacessível.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma e mais sofisticada de você fazer um teste para verificar se um host está acessivel no iOS é usando um conceito chamado Reachability.

O Reachability verifica se o dispositivo "alcançar" o destino através de uma determinada rota de rede e também consegue notificar seu app quando esta rede sofre alguma modificação.

Duas referencias que podem te ajudar bastante:

1. [Reachability by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)
2. [Reachability by Tony Million](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) (baseado em
   blocos)